# Create JSON Array with Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, swift4.2

I can't fetch json data from URL

I tried Alamofire, Swiftyjson and JSONDecoder but i didn't get any data

This is my json url result;

```swift
{
  "Firmalar": {
    "Firma": [
      {
        "SicilNo": "382",
        "FirmaAdi": "AYSAN PAMUK YAĞ VE YEM SANAYİ TİCARET ANONİM ŞİRKETİ",
        "Sektor": "GIDA ÜRÜNLERİ İMALATI ",
        "AcikAdres": "ACIDEREOSB MAHALLESİ FUZULİ CADDESİ NO: 2 ",
        "TelefonNo": "(322)394-5029",
        "FaksNo": "(322)394-4929",
        "EPosta": "mahmutkulak.aysanas@gmail.com",
        "WebAdresi": "www.aysanpamuk.com",
        "WebDurumu": "1",
        "TanitimFilmTR": "",
        "TanitimFilmEN": "",
        "TanitimBrosurTR": "",
        "TanitimBrosurEN": ""
      },      {
        "SicilNo": "1127",
        "FirmaAdi": "EKOVAR GERİ DÖNÜŞÜM MAKİNA İNŞAAT SAN. VE TİC. LTD. ŞTİ.",
        "Sektor": "DİĞER İMALATLAR",
        "AcikAdres": "ACIDEREOSB MAHALLESİ CUMHURİYET BULVARI NO: 26 ",
        "TelefonNo": "(312)442-1305",
        "FaksNo": "(312)442-1306",
        "EPosta": "mesut@ekovar.com.tr",
        "WebAdresi": "www.ekovar.com.tr",
        "WebDurumu": "1",
        "TanitimFilmTR": "",
        "TanitimFilmEN": "",
        "TanitimBrosurTR": "",
        "TanitimBrosurEN": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my struct;

```
struct Firmalar: Codable {
    let Firma: [FirmaModel]?
}

struct FirmaModel: Codable{
    let SicilNo:String?
    let FirmaAdi:String?
    let Sektor:String?
    let AcikAdres:String?
    let TelefonNo:String?
    let FaksNo:String?
    let EPosta:String?
    let WebAdresi:String?
    let TanitimFilmTR:String?
    let TanitimBrosurTR:String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case SicilNo="SicilNo", FirmaAdi="FirmaAdi", Sektor="Sektor", AcikAdres="AcikAdres", TelefonNo="TelefonNo", FaksNo="FaksNo", EPosta="EPosta", WebAdresi="WebAdresi", TanitimFilmTR="TanitimFilmTR", TanitimBrosurTR="TanitimBrosurTR"
    }
}
```

This is my fetchData Code;

```
 var firmalar = [Firmalar]()
    let searchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchFirmaData()
    }

    func fetchFirmaData(){
        let url = URL(string: "http://mobileapi.adanaorganize.org.tr/v1/firmalar")
        guard let downloadURL = url else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, response, error) in
            do{
                if error == nil {
                    self.firmalar = try JSONDecoder().decode([Firmalar].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(self.firmalar)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error While Geting Json Data: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

so my question is how can i create an array . using swift . here is my swift code. I get this error:  The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an array of `Firmalar` but a single value and that itself needs to be part of a separate root level struct  so change

```
self.firmalar = try JSONDecoder().decode([Firmalar].self, from: data!)
```

to

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
self.firmalar = result.Firmalar.Firma
```

and of course you need to change declaration of `firmalar` to

```
var firmalar = [FirmaModel]()
```

and include the root level struct

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let Firmalar: Firmalar
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. As you said, I've edited my code but I get an error; 
self.firmalar = result.Firma!
Thread 8: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @EmreŞekeroğlu Sorry, I obviously failed to save my updated, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all **never** print `error.localizedDescription`, it returns a generic quite meaningless error message. Print always just `error`.

The real error is

> Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead

The error is pretty clear. Look at the JSON. The root object is a dictionary, the value for key `Firma` is the array you are looking for.

You have to add another struct for the root object and decode this

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let firmalar: Firmalar

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case firmalar = "Firmalar" }
}

struct Firmalar: Codable {
    let firma: [FirmaModel]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case firma = "Firma" }
}

struct FirmaModel: Codable { ...
```

Declare the data source array

```
var firmaModel = [FirmaModel]()
```

and decode the JSON

```
if error == nil {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
    self.firmaModel = result.firmalar.firma
```

Declare all struct members as non-optional and with lowercased members mapped by the `CodingKeys` like in my suggested structs.

Comment: Thank you for your support. As you said, I've edited my code but I get an error; 
self.firmaModel = firmalar.Firma!
Thread 8: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value